# How do I rebind a combobox in winforms?

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a Winforms application and a combobox has it's datasource set to a DataTable when the form loads. The data displays fine in the combobox.

Then after a user clicks a button I want to create a new DataTable and assign that datatable as the datasource for the combobox.

The problem is that after setting the datasource to be the new datatable the items in the combobox don't change. Here is the code I'm using.

```
dlCustomer.DataSource = Nothing
        dlCustomer.DataSource = dtCustomers
        dlCustomer.DisplayMember = "Name"
        dlCustomer.Refresh()
```

Does anyone know how to make the correct data be displayed in the combobox the second time I assign the data source for it?

Comment: Just to double-check; are you binding it at design-time?  Is it bound to a bindingsource and then in turn to a datatable (default designer behavior) or is the binding done in code directly to a DataTable?

Answer (score 5):

It should work, at least it did in a quick test I threw together.  Here's the code; it just expects a Form with a ComboBox and Button:

```
    Public Class Form1

        Private dtOne As DataTable
        Private dtTwo As DataTable

        Private Sub InitializeTables()
            dtOne = New DataTable("TableOne")
            With dtOne
                .Columns.Add("Text", GetType(String))
                .Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Integer))
            End With

            dtTwo = New DataTable("TableTwo")
            With dtTwo
                .Columns.Add("Text", GetType(String))
                .Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Integer))
            End With

            Dim newRow As DataRow
            For index As Integer = 0 To 2
                newRow = dtOne.NewRow
                newRow.ItemArray = (New Object() {SpellIt(index), index})
                dtOne.Rows.Add(newRow)
            Next

            For index As Integer = 2 To 0 Step -1
                newRow = dtTwo.NewRow
                newRow.ItemArray = (New Object() {SpellIt(index), index})
                dtTwo.Rows.Add(newRow)
            Next

            dtOne.AcceptChanges()
            dtTwo.AcceptChanges()

        End Sub

        Private Shared Function SpellIt(ByVal int As Integer) As String
            Select Case int
                Case 0 : Return "Zero"
                Case 1 : Return "One"
                Case 2 : Return "Two"
                Case Else : Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Bleh!")
            End Select
        End Function

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            InitializeTables()

            Me.Label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ComboBox1, "SelectedValue")

            Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = dtOne
            Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text"
            Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"

        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Me.ComboBox1.DataBindings.Clear()
            Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing

            Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = dtTwo
            Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text"
            Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"

        End Sub

    End Class
```